# Quickly Categorizing Character Vector in R

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I have a dataset with a column of messy character data. I'd like to convert it to factorial data for analysis.

```
carData <- data.frame(car=c("Mustang", "Toyota Tercel", "M3", "Datsun 240Z", "Chevy Malibu"), 
                 year=c("2001", "1994", "2004", "1980", "2000"))

            car year
1       Mustang 2001
2 Toyota Tercel 1994
3            M3 2004
4   Datsun 240Z 1980
5  Chevy Malibu 2000
```

I've created a couple of lists to aid with this, one with a list of search strings, and another with the associated categories.

```
cars <- c("Mustang", "Toyota", "M3", "Chevy")
make <- c("Ford", "Toyota", "BMW", "Chevrolet")
```

My intent is to loop over the list and assign the category in a new variable.

```
categorize <- function(df, searchString, category) {
  df$make <- "OTHER"
  for(i in seq(1, length(searchString), 1)) {
    list <- grep(searchString[i], df[,1], ignore.case=TRUE)
    if (length(list) > 0) {
      for(j in seq(1, length(list), 1)) {
        df$make[list[j]] <- category[i]
      }
    }
  }
  df
}

cleanCarData <- categorize(carData, cars, make)
```

Output is:

```
            car year      make
1       Mustang 2001      Ford
2 Toyota Tercel 1994    Toyota
3            M3 2004       BMW
4   Datsun 240Z 1980     OTHER
5  Chevy Malibu 2000 Chevorlet
```

My code works, my issue is that my data has ~1M rows and it takes ~3 hours to complete. Conversely, if I create a lined statement for each, it takes less than 3 minutes to complete all of them.

```
df$make <- "OTHER"
df$make[grep("Mustang", df$car, ignore.case=TRUE)] <- "Ford"
df$make[grep...]
```

I have 50 search strings so far and could easily have 100 more as I work my way through the data. Is there a good compromise between maintainable code and performance?

Comment: Would looping over `cars` and `make` to construct the `df$make[...` statements help? I.e. `for (i in seq_along(cars)) df$make[grep(cars[i], df$car, ignore.case=TRUE)] <- make(i)`?

Comment: You could copy the `car` over to `make` and change factor levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make things better by eliminating the inner loop

```
categorize <- function(df, searchString, category) {
  df$make <- "OTHER"
  for(i in seq_along(searchString)) {
    list <- grep(searchString[i], df[,1], ignore.case=TRUE)
    if (length(list) > 0) {
      df$make[list] <- category[i]
    }
  }
  df
}
```

This is hard to test at scale to see if that'a where most of your time is spent because your sample data isn't very large.

Comment: Fantastic. This ran against my entire dataset in 12s, which is faster than my 50 lines of grep statements. It never occurred to me to try this without the nested loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is a possibility:

```
cleanCarData = carData
for(k in 1:length(cars)) {
    sel=grep(cars[k], as.character(cleanCarData$car))
    cleanCarData[sel,"make"] = make[k]
}
cleanCarData$make[is.na(cleanCarData$make)] = "OTHER"
```